# ASP.NET MVC2 localization: How to format language/country dependend text?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, resources, localization

I want to build an multi language ASP.NET MVC 2 website.

Let's say I have the following sentences:

```
MyStrings.resx:
TestString : "This is my test"

MyStrings.de.resx:
TestString : "Dies ist mein Test"

MyStrings.fr.resx:
TestString : "C'est mon test"
```

Now on my site I want to make the words my/mein/mon in an other color. For example I want to asssign an other span class. What is the best/standard practice to do that?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You could mix HTML into your resource: `"This is <span class="x">my</span> test"`
2. You could use `string.Format`: Resource: `"This is {0}my{1} test"` , use: `string.Format(Resources.TestString, "<span class=\"x\">", "</span">)`.
3. You could use some custom formatting scheme: For example resource: `"This is --my-- test"`, and write some extension method accepting a string, and replacing all `--` with the right tags.

**UPDATE**
 4. You can use custom format method. See code below.

Your resource could look like `Hello {firstname}, you still have {amount} {currency} in your bankaccount.`  You would "consume" this resource in the following way:

```
Resources.Bla.Bla.FormatWith(new { Firstname = SomeVariable, AMOUNT = 4, currency = "USD"  });
```

As you can see, it is case insensitive, and you can mix in constants and variables.  I made a custom translation web app, where I check if the translator uses all of the "variables" that are present in the original English string. That is quite an important check according to me.
Let me do add that this way is a bit controversial, since it uses reflection, but I find that the pros weigh heavier than the cons.

```
public static string FormatWith(this string format, object source)
    {
        StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder(format.Length);
        StringBuilder sbCurrentTerm = new StringBuilder();
        char[] formatChars = format.ToCharArray();
        bool inTerm = false;
        object currentPropValue = source;

        var sourceProps = source.GetType().GetProperties();

        for (int i = 0; i < format.Length; i++)
        {
            if (formatChars[i] == '{')
                inTerm = true;
            else if (formatChars[i] == '}')
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = sourceProps.First(sp=>sp.Name.Equals(sbCurrentTerm.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                sbResult.Append((string)(pi.PropertyType.GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { }).Invoke(pi.GetValue(currentPropValue, null) ?? string.Empty, null)));
                sbCurrentTerm.Clear();
                inTerm = false;
                currentPropValue = source;
            }
            else if (inTerm)
            {
                if (formatChars[i] == '.')
                {
                    PropertyInfo pi = currentPropValue.GetType().GetProperty(sbCurrentTerm.ToString());
                    currentPropValue = pi.GetValue(source, null);
                    sbCurrentTerm.Clear();
                }
                else
                    sbCurrentTerm.Append(formatChars[i]);
            }
            else
                sbResult.Append(formatChars[i]);
        }
        return sbResult.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Way 1 seems very good. But then I need to take care of escaping special chars on my own :-( Is one of these three ways "standard" way like nearly everyone is solving this issue?

Comment: I do it on a 4th way, I'll add it here.

Comment: Basically my way looks like nr 2, but with named elements, such as "This is {italics}my{enditalics} test." I use a custom Format function that gets an object, and applies the properties of the object to the input string. For me it was the best way, becuase I have a huge amount of resources, and many different people working on them. Having named items, helps them understand, and keeps them from mixing things up. If you want I can post the custom format extension method. Which I took from somebody, and made some minor tweaks.

Comment: Thank you again. I would really appreciate it very much if you could post your custom format extension method. Your 4th way would make it easier for the translator as this person does not need to know styling.

Comment: I will post it on Sunday, I'm not near my computer right now.

Comment: I'm happy I could be of help.